# Sort List of object based on start date of the course

Tags: java, collections, compareto

I need to sort a list of courses with a start date the dates is Strings.

The sort should be based on the start date, my date in the list is looks like:

- 03:20
- 04:10
- 09:40
- 08:00
- 08:50
- 01:50
- 02:30

**Note** That the sort here is custom and every item with start date from 01 until 07 should be below dates from 08 until 12

for example the list above will be:

- 08:00
- 08:50
- 09:40
- 01:50
- 02:30
- 03:20
- 04:10

How can I achieve this, I tried this:

```
int compare = this.getStartDate().compareTo(o.getStartDate());
if (compare > 0 && this.getStartDate().charAt(1) >= '1' && this.getStartDate().charAt(1) <= '7')
        return -1;
if (compare < 0 && o.getStartDate().charAt(1) < '1' && o.getStartDate().charAt(1) > '7')
        return 1;
return compare;
```

Comment: Start by using the correct type: LocalTime. Not String.

Comment: Do what @JBNizet stated and then find out that `LocalTime` already implements `Comparable` and just use it for sorting.

Comment: @deHaar it's a bit more complex that that, since he doesn't want to use the natural ordering. But still, using the right type is always a good idea.

Comment: @JBNizet OP wants a sorting in natural order, at least it appears to me he does... Missing AM/PM flags are confusing.

Comment: @deHaar with natural ordering, 01:50 would come before 08:00.

Comment: Yeah it's a little bit not like the natural order, the dates is presented to the app through json response and yeah AM/PM is missing.

Comment: You need to write a custom comparator. If the two times are both under 8:00, or both after 8:00, you compare them with their natural order. If not, then the one after 8:00 is always lower than the one before 08:00.

Comment: Do you have any courses starting at 1:50 AM, like nearly two hours after midnight? Otherwise this order lools (chronologically) natural to me, but nevermind. There are decent answers and suggestions, have a look at those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method that converts the times below "08:00" to times greater than "12:00" by adding 12 to the hour part:

```
public static String getValue(String s) {
    String[] splitted = s.split(":");
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
    if (hour < 8) {
        hour += 12;
        splitted[0] = String.valueOf(hour);
    }
    return splitted[0] + ":" + splitted[1];
}
```

now compare like this:

```
return getValue(this.getStartDate()).compareTo(getValue(o.getStartDate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

Don’t represent your time of day by strings in your model. Use a proper time-of-day class. Java has one built in (from Java 8 and on; also backported to Java 6 and 7): `LocalTime`.

```
public class Course implements Comparable<Course> {

    private static final LocalTime START_OF_COURSE_DAY = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
    /** Constant for PM of day (afternoon) */
    private static final int PM = 1;
    private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm");

    LocalTime time;

    /**
     * @param timeString
     *          If the time string begins with 08 through 11, it is in AM, otherwise in PM
     */
    public Course(String timeString) {
        // Even though the time string is in either AM or PM,
        // just parse the hour as hour of day and adjust afterward.
        time = LocalTime.parse(timeString);
        if (time.isBefore(START_OF_COURSE_DAY)) {
            // time is in PM
            time = time.with(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, PM);
        }
        // toString() should give the same string back
        if (! toString().equals(timeString)) {
            System.out.println("Unexpected time format: " + timeString);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Course o) {
        return time.compareTo(o.time);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return time.format(TIME_FORMATTER);
    }

}
```

Since `LocalTime` is comparable (has a natural order that agrees with the ordering we want), the implementation of `compareTo` is a one-liner.

Let’s try it out:

```
        List<Course> listOfCourses = Arrays.asList(
                new Course("03:20"),
                new Course("04:10"),
                new Course("09:40"),
                new Course("08:00"),
                new Course("08:50"),
                new Course("01:50"),
                new Course("02:30"),
                new Course("12:30"));
        listOfCourses.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());

        listOfCourses.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output is:

> ```
> 08:00
> 08:50
> 09:40
> 12:30
> 01:50
> 02:30
> 03:20
> 04:10
> ```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.